# Copying observations into the empty entries within the same variable

Tags: stata

I just imported data from Excel. However, due to the collection process, certain entries are empty. For example, for Variable 1, my observations might be like:

```
1
[empty]
[empty]
2
[empty]
3
[empty]
[empty]
[empty]
```

I now want to fill these empty entries with the non-empty before it. Thus, using the example above, I want to produce something like:

```
1
1
1
2
2
3
3
3
3
```

As you can see, I want to fill the empty slots with the non-empty slot preceding it. I tried this block of code:

```
gen Judge1p = Judge1
forvalues x = 1/1395 {
    if Judge1[`x'] != "" replace Judge1p[`x'] = Judge1[`x']
    else replace Judge1p[`x'] = Judge1p[`x'-1]
    }
```

However, Stata shows the error of "weights not allowed" and I did a little search online. It says that Stata doesn't allow users to put [`x'] before an equal sign. I'm a bit stuck here. What's the best way to solve the problem?

Comment: I don't know why "search online" is needed here. Everything you need to know is included in the `help` for `replace` which shows that `if` or `in` qualifiers provide the (only) syntax for replacing in specific observations. The larger point, already made, is that no loop is needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear what `[empty]` means. I assume they are missing.
Below is an example; no need for a loop.

```
clear all
set more off

*----- example data -----

input ///
var1
1
1
.
.
.
6
.
.
.
4
5
.
.
end

list

*----- what you want -----

gen var2 = var1
replace var2 = cond(missing(var2), var2[_n-1], var2)

list
```

Many things can be done in Stata without explicit loops. A reference is

Cox, Nicholas J. “**Speaking Stata: How to Repeat Yourself without Going Mad.**” Stata Journal 1, no. 1 (2001): 86–97.

Missings in Stata are represented as `.` for numerical type and  (blank) for string type. If you need something more complicated, you'll have to make it clear in your post.

See `help <command>` for anything that is not clear.

Imputation of missings is a big topic in statistical analysis, so make sure you know what you're doing.

Comment: In addition note that this is an FAQ: http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/